# How to detect which HPC scheduler (Torque, Sun Grid Engine etc) am I using?

Tags: hpc, pbs, sungridengine, torque

I need to run a different script depending on the type of scheduler, which necessitates a reliable way to detect if the scheduler is Torque, SGE or something else. Something like $SHELL telling which shell I am using. or something like name.

I am aware of [environmental variables](https://kb.iu.edu/d/avgl) the two systems set, but they don't offer me a *reliable* or an elegant way - given the commands the env. variables are named similarly or identically.. there needs to several ifs and buts before we can conclude which is it.

Comment: Each of these exports a set of environment variables. Look for those to see what scheduler was used to launch your job. Or just read the documentation of your system.

Comment: well, I am aware of those, they don't offer me a **reliable** or an elegant way - given the commands the env. variables are named similarly or identically.. there needs to several ifs and buts before we can conclude which is it.

Answer (score 1):

Set an environment variable explicitly in your `.bashrc` that you can later query.

e.g.

```
export RUNNING_ON="moms_gpu_cluster5"
export THIS_SYSTEMS_SCHEDULER="SGE"
```

You won't have to rely on what the sysadmin gives you, or what the scheduler does or doesn't do.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer an automatic method that would help me derive it from the system config, and not rely on user settings.